# HSET if key exist

Tags: redis

Redis don't support HSET only if key exist. 
http://redis.io/commands#hash
What will be the best way to achieve that functionality in client ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's easy to implement it on the client side using transaction.

```
WATCH hkey
isKeyExists = EXISTS hkey
if isKeyExists
  MULTI
  HSET hkey field value
  EXEC
else
  UNWATCH
```

When the hkey is removed after WATCH, the transaction will fail.

You can also use the scripting that was introduced in the Redis 2.6.

Comment: It is not doing anything, If I fire it from redis-cli. 
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL hkey
1) "v"
2) "r"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> WATCH hkey isKeyExists = EXISTS hkey if isKeyExists   MULTI   HSET hkey field value   EXEC else   UNWATCH
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> HGETALL hkey
1) "v"
2) "r"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379>

Comment: Sorry not having explained clearly. What I wrote is pseudocode that is used in the redis document. See more: http://redis.io/topics/transactions

Comment: if the contents of hkey changed after 'WATCH' command, 'HSET' command will fail to execute. that's not 'HSET if key exist'.

Comment: I think this SO provided a correct answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605567/how-to-do-hset-only-if-key-exists-with-redis/