# How to do HSET only if key exists with Redis?

Tags: redis

I want to run a `HSET` command but only if the key exists. Similar to `HSETNX` except `exists` instead of `not exists`

I've read about maybe using WATCH or something but so far I can't really figure it out. I would appreciate a nudge in the right direction. The only thing I see is this but I don't see how this works considering these aren't even valid redis commands.

[HSET if key exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009778/hset-if-key-exist)

Also, after reading about WATCH that concerns me because I don't want to abort the transaction if another request comes it.

I'm basically trying to HGETALL and immediately after issue a second command for HSET, saying that it has been read a single time.

After that, I want all subsequent requests to know that it's already been read.

The problem is, when I call HSET on a key that doesn't exist, instead of just failing it creates a new entry in the redis database, which I don't want. I only want it to update records if it exists without having to check if it exists first

According to this, that method won't work anyway for high contention (there will be lots of requests to the key)

https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/441

It says I could use scripting somehow but I'm not sure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You can execute a lua script in Redis by running `EVAL` command. All the commands after the `EVAL` will be blocked until the `EVAL` has completed, since Redis is a single-threaded server.

The documentation says:

> EVAL and EVALSHA are used to evaluate scripts using the Lua interpreter built into Redis starting from version 2.6.0.

So, it's easy to implement a simple `HSETX` command，just run the lua script below:

`eval "if redis.call('exists',KEYS[1]) == 1 then redis.call('hset', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], 0) end" 1 test_key test_field`

Comment: dude awesome, thank you. Can you tell me how I also chain a 2nd command in there? I acutally want to call HGETALL and HSET right after each other .. so` if exists;  hgetall; set; else; do nothing`

Comment: @Tallboy 
eval "if redis.call('exists',KEYS[1]) == 1 then local ret = redis.call('hgetall', KEYS[1]); redis.call('hset', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], 1) return ret end" 1 test_key test_field